# Interface name already in use when using Repository pattern

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I'm adapting repository pattern in a laravel application by creating the interface of a repository for a given model under the namespace of `App\Repositories\Interfaces`, and then creating the implementation class under the namespace `App\Repositories`, after that i bind the interface to the class in `RepositoryServiceProvider`.

Everything was going fine at first, but when I've created repository files for *Grade* model and trying to do `php artisan route:list`, or accessing a *grade/* route I get this:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException thrown with message **"Cannot declare interface App\Repositories\Interfaces\GradeRepositoryInterface, because the name is already in use"**

Ok!, seems obvious, change the interface name and your good to go!, well NO.

- the same error is raised with the same new interface name.
- changing the namespace does not work either!.

> I was running composer dump-autolod after changes.

Interface declaration:

```php
use App\Models\Grade;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\BaseRepository;

interface GradeRepositoryInterface extends BaseRepository
{
    public function get(int $id) : Grade;
    public function edit(int $id, array $data);
    public function delete(int $id) : bool;
}
```

I highly doubt that symfony, or laravel have `GradeRepositoryInterface` interface.
Any **suggestions**? (Hopefully solutions)

Comment: Can it be it's just double loaded?

Comment: The way you've described should work. Make sure you do not have a `GradeRepositoryInterface` with the same namespace (could be a in a different folder). Other than that make sure all caches are cleared

Comment: @PtrTon no interface `GradeRepositoryInterface` other than mine, but do you mean by `Other than that make sure all caches are cleared`?

Comment: @onlineThomas how is that?

Comment: If you remove the interface entirely, does ```php artisan route:list``` work again?

Comment: Maybe because of automatic dependency injection or something along those lines

Comment: @Etin only disabling `Route::resource('grade', 'School\GradeController');` in web.php make `php artisan route:list` work, this should mean the interface is dicovered without error when binding it with the class in `RepositoryServiceProvider`

Comment: @onlineThomas I don't see how this is the problem, there are other dependency injections working fine.

Comment: That's why it's a comment

Comment: My guess is that the GradeRepositoryInterface was cached the first time it was declared. You'll need to purge caches. Inspect the file 'vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php' to see if it exists twice.

Comment: @Etin it exists only one time, how to purge cache?

Comment: Please delete the Interface, then run ```composer dump-autoload``` and inspect that file to see if it's still there.

Comment: @Etin it's still there !

Comment: Rename the file 'vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php' to 'vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php.old'. Then create your RepositoryInterface and run ```composer dump-autoload```. Then try ```php artisan route:list``` again.

Comment: @Etin bad news :/ , still the same error!

Comment: Ah. I'm almost out of ideas. :-( Might have to wait for someone with more experience to come along?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198473/discussion-between-etin-and-joe-inz).

Answer (score -2):

Changed the name like `GradesRepositroyInterface`, and `composer dump-autoload` again